# SQL how to show list of people with no orders

Tags: sql-server-express

I'm trying to solve this SQL query    (it's in French)

I've got 4 different tables : CLIENT , COMMANDE (order), DETAIL (of the orders) and PRODUIT (product)

**I have to give the number(NCLI) and the name(NOM) of the clients of 'Namur'(that is in the LOCALITE)  that haven't made any orders (COMMANDE) in a query**

I've tried different things, last code i had in my SQL express was this one (wich of course doesn't work.

```
 select NCLI, NOM
 from   CLIENT
 where  LOCALITE = 'Namur' and (NCLI in (select NCLI             
                                   from COMMANDE
                                   where NCOM in (select NCOM
                                                  from DETAIL
                                                  where QCOM not in DETAIL)))
```

**Could anyone help me out with this?**

in case it is needed this is the code of my existing tables and of the inserts:

```
create table CLIENT
(NCLI char(4) not null,
 NOM  varchar(12) not null,
 ADRESSE varchar(20) not null,
 LOCALITE varchar(12) not null,
 CAT char(2),
 COMPTE decimal(9,2) not null,
 primary key (NCLI));

create table PRODUIT
(NPRO char(5) not null,
LIBELLE varchar(20) not null,
PRIX decimal(5,0) not null,
QSTOCK decimal(6,0) not null,
primary key (NPRO));

  create table COMMANDE
 (NCOM char(5) not null,
 NCLI char(4) not null,
 DATECOM datetime not null,
 primary key (NCOM),
 foreign key (NCLI) references CLIENT);

 create table DETAIL
 (NCOM char(5) not null,
 NPRO char(5) not null,
 QCOM decimal(4,0) not null,
 primary key (NCOM,NPRO),
 foreign key (NCOM) references COMMANDE,
 foreign key (NPRO) references PRODUIT);




 insert into CLIENT values ('B112','HANSENNE'    ,'23, a. Dumont'       ,'Poitiers' ,'C1',1250.00);
 insert into CLIENT values ('C123','MERCIER'     ,'25, r. Lemaitre'     ,'Namur'    ,'C1',-2300);
 insert into CLIENT values ('B332','MONTI'       ,'112, r. Neuve'       ,'Geneve'   ,'B2',0);
 insert into CLIENT values ('F010','TOUSSAINT'   ,'5, r. Godefroid'     ,'Poitiers' ,'C1',0);
 insert into CLIENT values ('K111','VANBIST'     ,'180, r. Florimont'   ,'Lille'    ,'B1',720);
 insert into CLIENT values ('S127','VANDERKA'    ,'3, av. des Roses'    ,'Namur'    ,'C1',-4580);
 insert into CLIENT values ('B512','GILLET'      ,'14, r. de l''Ete'    ,'Toulouse' ,'B1',-8700);
 insert into CLIENT values ('B062','GOFFIN'      ,'72, r. de la Gare'   ,'Namur'    ,'B2',-3200);
 insert into CLIENT values ('C400','FERARD'      ,'65, r. du Tertre'    ,'Poitiers' ,'B2',350);
 insert into CLIENT values ('C003','AVRON'       ,'8, ch. de la Cure'   ,'Toulouse' ,'B1',-1700);
 insert into CLIENT values ('K729','NEUMAN'      ,'40, r. Bransart'     ,'Toulouse' ,NULL,0);
 insert into CLIENT values ('F011','PONCELET'    ,'17, Clos des Erables','Toulouse' ,'B2',0);
 insert into CLIENT values ('L422','FRANCK'      ,'60, r. de Wepion'    ,'Namur'    ,'C1',0);
 insert into CLIENT values ('S712','GUILLAUME'   ,'14a, ch. des Roses'  ,'Paris'    ,'B1',0);
 insert into CLIENT values ('D063','MERCIER'       ,'201, bvd du Nord'  ,'Toulouse' ,NULL,-2250);
 insert into CLIENT values ('F400','JACOB'       ,'78, ch. du Moulin'   ,'Bruxelles','C2',0);

 insert into PRODUIT values ('CS262','CHEV. SAPIN 200x6x2',  75,  45);
 insert into PRODUIT values ('CS264','CHEV. SAPIN 200x6x4', 120,2690);
 insert into PRODUIT values ('CS464','CHEV. SAPIN 400x6x4', 220, 450);
 insert into PRODUIT values ('PA45' ,'POINTE ACIER 45 (1K)',105, 580);
 insert into PRODUIT values ('PA60' ,'POINTE ACIER 60 (1K)', 95, 134);
 insert into PRODUIT values ('PH222','PL. HETRE 200x20x2',  230, 782);
 insert into PRODUIT values ('PS222','PL. SAPIN 200x20x2',  185,1220);

 insert into COMMANDE values ('30178','K111','20081221');
 insert into COMMANDE values ('30179','C400','20081222');
 insert into COMMANDE values ('30182','S127','20081223');
 insert into COMMANDE values ('30184','C400','20081223');
 insert into COMMANDE values ('30185','F011','20090102');
 insert into COMMANDE values ('30186','C400','20090102');
 insert into COMMANDE values ('30188','B512','20090103');

 insert into DETAIL values ('30178','CS464',25);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30179','PA60',20);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30179','CS262',60);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30182','PA60',30);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30184','CS464',120);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30184','PA45',20);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30185','PA60',15);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30185','PS222',600);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30185','CS464',260);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30186','PA45',3);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30188','PA60',70);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30188','PH222',92);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30188','CS464',180);
 insert into DETAIL values ('30188','PA45',22);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
select c.NCLI, c.NOM
 from   CLIENT c
 where  c.LOCALITE = 'Namur' and c.NCLI NOT IN  (select NCLI             
                                   from COMMANDE)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Could you tell me what the c. is for? I noticed it works without the c too. Or is the c needed for another Database program?

Comment: The `c` there is an alias. If the same name columns are present in multiple tables, `c.column_name` notation helps the database understand which particular column is meant in the query.

Answer (score 1):

why not try this:

```
select NCLI,NOM
      from CLIENT
      WHERE LOCALITE = 'NAMUR' AND NOT EXISTS(
                                            SELECT *
                                            FROM COMMANDE 
                                            WHERE CLIENT.NCLI = COMMANDE .NCLI)
```